# Trouble reading multiple child nodes (Firebase)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm very new to Firebase and fairly new to Swift as well, so please excuse any improper syntax. I am having some trouble reading data that is under multiple child nodes in Firebase, data shows up when under one child node but under essentially the same conditions is nil when I try to locate it under two.

```
adminClientHandle = ref.child("Test").child("client1").observe(.value, with : { (snapshot) in
            let adminClientStuff = snapshot.value as? [String:String]

            //Goals
            if adminClientStuff?["Goal 1"] != nil {
                self.adminGoal1.text = adminClientStuff?["Goal 1"]
            } else {
                self.adminGoal1.text = "nil"
            }
```

`ref = Database.database().reference()` on `viewDidLoad`

when firebase database looks like this:

```
{
  "Test" : {
    "client1" : {
      "Goal 1" : "Goal 1",
      "Goal 1 %" : "100",
      "Goal 1 Correct" : 1,
      "Goal 1 Total" : "1",
      "Goal 2" : "Will keep personal space for 10 minutes",
      "Goal 2 %" : "0",
      "Goal 2 Correct" : 1,
      "Goal 2 Total" : "1",
      "Goal 3" : "Will recall events that happened in the last hour",
      "Goal 3 %" : "0",
      "Goal 3 Correct" : 1,
      "Goal 3 Total" : "1"
    }
  }
}
```

`adminClientStuff?["Goal 1"]` returns `nil`, even though a similar code with on child node returns an actual string. Please let me know if there's anything I could potentially be missing, but I've tried a lot without the desired result.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a snippet of the actual JSON at `ref` (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Gotcha just did, thanks!

Comment: At first glance the code looks aligned with the JSON you shared. What gets shown when you print `adminClientStuff`?

Comment: It looks like it returns nothing at all, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: OK, that means no data whatsoever gets loaded. It can't be a security/authorization issue, since that would not call this completion handler. The only thing I can think of is that `ref` is not pointing to the root of the JSON you shared, so you might want to print that `ref` and see what it points to. If that's not it, I hope somebody else spots the problem.

Comment: Okay cool, thanks for the help. I'll comment if I figure out what's wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your structure, there's a mixture of values in it

```
  "Goal 1" : "Goal 1",
  "Goal 1 %" : "100",
  "Goal 1 Correct" : 1,
```

so this won't work as it's a heterogeneous collection literal issue

```
let adminClientStuff = snapshot.value as? [String:String]
```

It will need to be defined like this

```
let adminClientStuff = snapshot.value as? [String:Any]
```

I would also suggest a different solution as well that protects your code in case a value is missing or not what is expected.

```
let goal1 = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "Goal 1").value as? String ?? "No Goal value"
let goal1Percent = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "Goal 1 %").value as? String ?? "No Goal value"
let goal1Correct = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "Goal 1 Correct").value as? Int ?? 0
print(goal1, goal1Percent, goal1Correct)
```

Comment: I thought I had cast all my data as strings when writing it to Firebase, but I must have missed something. Anyways, good first experience asking Stack Overflow!